# Requesting [input] on [user-input]

Tags: discussion, tags

There are two tags, [input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/input) and [user-input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user-input), what is the difference between those? Should they be merged?

Comment: Looks like two overly-broad tags to me...

Comment: Well, there is an HTML element named `input`.

Comment: @TinyGiant which is [tag:html-input], in fact, the tag wiki says to not use [tag:input] for `<input>`

Comment: +0, not punny enough.

Comment: The difference is one of them would take longer to burinate because it has over 7 times as many questions. Sadly, the bigger one is also the most egregious of the two, but those properties correlate strongly.

Comment: I agree with Andrew, a better title could be something like `requesting [input] on [user-input]`

Comment: @KeithHall corrected

Comment: @AndrewGrimm It is punny now.

Comment: I say burn 'em both